# Issue with tracking related events using Operation Context

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a WPF application that I would like to monitor using Application Insights. I would like to group each user action as one request, with embedded custom events and dependency calls. From what I read in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics) operation context should be the right way to go. I wrote the following code:

```cs
using (var operation = telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>(
      $"test operation {Guid.NewGuid()}"))
{
    telemetryClient.TrackEvent("my test event");
    telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I check the Application Insights portal "my test event" does not appear as a related event to the request event. I experimented a bit and found that if I set the operation properties manually the events become related:

```cs
using (var operation = telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>(
      $"test operation {Guid.NewGuid()}"))
{
    var ev = new EventTelemetry("test event");
    ev.Context.Operation.Id = operation.Telemetry.Context.Operation.Id;
    ev.Context.Operation.Name = operation.Telemetry.Context.Operation.Name;
    telemetryClient.TrackEvent(ev);
    telemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
}
```

But I have a feeling that it should not look like this. So my question is: could someone point me what I'm doing wrong in the first snippet? Is there some magical setting on the `TelemetryClient` which makes it behave as it is stated in the documentation?

Comment: It is only generated by default in an ASP.Net context. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#operation-context: You can associate telemetry items together by attaching to them a common operation ID. The standard request-tracking module does this for exceptions and other events that are sent while an HTTP request is being processed. In my WinForm app I have to set it myself also.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons. It looks that this manual procedure is a must here. I will refactor the code so it looks better. You may put your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relatively simple way to ensure all outgoing telemetry in the same context has the same operation id, name, etc. is to use a TelemetryInitializer with CallContext.

[This is a really good blog post](https://dzimchuk.net/event-correlation-in-application-insights/) that shows how to do it.

Comment: That's actually a nice idea. Thanks!